# Which dragon for which race?

Tags: dragonvale

So the update has added in a race track where you can pay 50,000 (so far) to enter your dragon and then race it. Unlike most things in Dragonvale this is an interactive race and dragon selection has a large impact upon the outcome as the dragons naturally move faster in the environments they are attuned to and move slower in ones that are their opposites.

What I am after is a list of the race tracks and their elements. I can guess at some of them but some times I am very far off (I thought shimmering was ice, instead it was lightning for example).

Comment: I think you meant Dragonvale, not Dragon **value**, though I have to admit I would be interested in playing the latter if it exists :)

Comment: Whoops! That would be why it didn't show up right I suppose!

Comment: The full list can be found [on the wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Track).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dramoria - Cold, Metal

Year of the Dragon - Earth, Water, Air, Fire

Blast Furnace - Fire, Metal

Ulster Meadows - Earth, Plant

Rime or Reason - Air, Cold

Marsh Lands - Plant, Water, Earth

Cherry Road - Fire, Plant, Earth

Shimmering Faultline - Lightning, Earth

Electric Skies - Lightning, Air

Radiant Run - Light, Water

Shining Valley - Light, Plant

Brightless Vale - Dark, Earth

Darkened Dash - Dark, Fire

Comment: Ran a lot of races last night and these were spot on and I did not find a race not in this list. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here are additional dragons you can win with based on track elements. I am including gem dragons that will win in each category as well.

Rime & Reason - (Air+Cold) Olympus, Snow, Blizzard
Dramoria - (Metal+Ice) Mine, Olympus, Rainbow, Steel
Electric Skies - (Lightning+Air) *RUBY, Sonic, Lunar Eclipse, Olympus, Thunder
Blast Furnace - (Fire+Metal) *Ruby, Forge, Brass, Olympus, Brass
Year Of The Dragon - (Fire+Air+Earth+Water) *Sapphire, *Opal, Panlong, Bone, *Panalog
Cherry Road - (Fire+Plant+Earth) *Opal,  Olympus, Sakura- if not, Panalog
Ulster Meadows - (Plant+Earth) *Peridot, Tree, Moss
Marshlands - (Water+Plant+Earth) *Pearl, Swamp, Olympus, Seaweed
Shimmering Faultline - (Lightning,Earth) *Emerald, *Peridot, Quake, Crystal

My experience shows that the gem dragons do very well as long as you use the ones I listed for each race. I always choose the gem dragon if available in my list for a particular race. The strongest dragons are gem, Panlong, and Olympus if available for that race. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Dramoria -  Mine dragon and Steel
Year of the Dragon - Panlong if you have it; if not - Blazing dragon
Blast Furnace - Forge dragon or Brass
Ulster Meadows - Tree dragon or Moss dragon
Rime or Reason - Snow dragon or Blizzard dragon
Marshlands - Swamp dragon or seaweed dragon
Cherry Road - Sakura dragon-if not, flower or poison
Shimmering Faultline - Crystal dragon or quake dragon
Electric Skies - Sonic dragon or thunder dragon

Comment: I have given this an upvote for posting some specific dragons but I am going to leave the other one as the answer because it explains the elements and with new dragons being added all the time other possibilities may exist!

Answer (score 1):

If you have them, it is best to use the **Rainbow** or **Leap Year** dragons. I use them and even if I only get '*great*' in the races, I finish 1st by quite a stretch. However, if you don't own them use the Panlong Dragon, but you will have to work harder :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I know:

- Electric skies:sonic dragon preferred, lightning and/or air dragons will work
- Shimmering faultine:quake dragon or crystal dragon
- Rime of reason:cold dragon or evergreen
- Marshlands:Sakura dragon or plant works
- Year of the dragon:Panlong if you have one; blazing or obsidian if not.
- Ulster meadows:Sakura dragon also or evergreen

Comment: You're just making guesses - and fairly bad ones in most cases - on what *might* work.