# What is the fastest strategy to obtain the Perch of Kairos (without gems)?

Tags: dragonvale

DragonVale recently added the [Perch of Kairos](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Perch_of_Kairos) habitat, which has to be built in 3 phases or "artifacts" using pieces called "time fragments".  The time fragments can be purchased with gems for a eye-poppingly large sum, or they can be won via the Dragon Track.  I definitely want to unlock [Kairos](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Kairos), but I'd rather not spend gems to do so.  What is the fastest strategy to unlock the Perch, without spending gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win lose or draw, you are going to be doing ***a lot*** of dragon races.  In order to ease the pain, I used the following process (and I now have Kairos):

1. **Gather your stable of racers**.  You can check out [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/78648/21619) for a list of all of the races, and the elements needed for each.  I suggest choosing one best dragon for each race, and leveling them to the cap (or at least above your other dragons), and adding an "A" to the start of their name.  This will make them easy to find when choosing a dragon for a race.
2. **Be impatient**.  As soon as your dragon crosses the finish, the "Red X" icon in the top right changes to a "Green Play" icon.  Pressing that will advance to the winners podiums without waiting for other dragons to finish.  At the podiums, you can also press "spin wheel" almost immediately once the screen loads.  This will save you several seconds per heat, which will add up over the hundreds of races necessary.
3. **Just spin the stupid wheel**.  There is a lot of misinformation about methods to control the result of the wheel.  While I'm not sure if the result is [predetermined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/83300/21619), or simply [uncontrollable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79814/21619) - I gave up trying to fix the odds and just spun as fast as I could.  If it is possible to control, it is damn hard - and I'd say the time you save by just spinning it and moving on is worth it in the long run.

I ended up pulling it off with no gems spent, so I can confirm it is possible.  While it's nice to have him, keep in perspective that his ability is on a 4 day cool down and it's not that amazing in my humble opinion.  In other words, don't feel like you are missing out on that much if you don't have him yet - just keep racing.

Answer (score 0):

Races are rigged. Whatever prize is on the wheel before you spin count up or down 6 prize items and I guarantee its the prize you get no matter how hard r soft you spin the wheel.

Comment: Hi Jim! Welcome to Arqade!  Your answer applies more to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79812/can-the-result-of-the-dragonvale-race-spin-be-controlled?lq=1), and someone has actually already given that answer.  Take a look and upvote answers you agree with!

Answer (score 0):

race and quest and much as you can, in the past 30 minutes alone, I got the last 2 pieces of the chronolith and 2 pieces of the time claw

Comment: @Hi 173106, welcome to Arqade!  Our format is a little different than a forum.  If you agree with one of the answers already given, you can upvote - and when you have more rep leave comments.  I see you mention quests, which my answer does not (since I already have Kairos, I don't know much about them).  If you could add details about the best way to quest - that would be a great answer.

Answer (score -1):

I got it in 3 hours just keep racing. Just remember all your dragon that you race that makes you win. And play it fast.